# How to copy and paste formatting from the bottom cell of a table to the next cell below it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that cuts cells out of a table if the entries' date is > 2 weeks old. It then Deletes these cells. However, this causes my formatted area for data entry to shorten each time, so I am trying to find a way to fix this. My idea was to write a piece to copy the formatting from the last formatted row and paste it directly below it, but I am not sure how to go about doing this in VBA. I am newer to VBA and was wondering if anyone knew how to help? Thank you!

Comment: Why not just `ClearContents` instead of cutting the cells? Or maybe I misunderstand what you're doing.

Comment: I used ClearContents for another part of this project, however I need the cells removed that contain the old dates, then if I don't delete them, it leaves big spaces in-between the data that isn't old. If there's a way to write it so that I can ClearContents then shift all cells below it up one for each time a cell is cleared, I could do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your goal is to basically have your data entry table ALSO be your summary table, hence wiping out all entries greater than 2 weeks old.  This seems like it will end up backfiring on you at some point - for example, what if you wanted to pull a report on everything you entered over the last year?

A better route would seem to be to have a single data entry sheet where you keep EVERYTHING and then a summary display that actively just pulls the data from the last two weeks.  For that, you could use VBA to filter your data set based upon the date and then copy the information over to the new sheet (just do it once manually using the filter tool from the Home tab on the ribbon, while recording your actions to a new macro, and you should be able to clean it up pretty easily).

If you MUST edit in place, and presuming you don't mind it being sorted by date, record a macro where you select your full formatted range, turn on filtering, filter by your date column, delete the contents (just use the delete key) of the cells you want to wipe out, and then sort by date on the rest.

The cause of your problem is that in using the range.delete command you are removing the cell from existence (and hence shrinking your formatted range) - you just want to wipe out the contents and then move all your data up to fill the blank space.

good luck!